# TWA: trying to do seamless navigation between domains and no luck

Tags: android, twa

I am trying to create a TWA app in Android Studio that might be working with all our domains and provide seamless navigation between them, but ran out of ideas.
The problem is this - when browsing within one domain all is fine, the "back" button on the phone returns to a previously browsed page. But as soon as you switch to another domain, it looks like the app re-initializes, and the "back" button does not lead back to the previous domain's page. Instead, it minifies the app...

All domains contain Digital Asset files in respective folders, fingerprints are ok, app works perfectly with each individual domain but keeps acting as you've just opened it upon trying to pass from one domain to another via a link.

All domains are added in separate `<data>` tags under intent-filter with `action.view` and categories `DEFAULT` and `BROWSABLE` in manifest.
Tried adding relations in asset statements to every one of them but no luck getting desired result.

Maybe someone could make it to work? Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Chunks of my silly newb code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.domain.newsapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

        <activity
            android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.LauncherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">


            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL"
                android:value="https://sub1.domain.ru/" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.STATUS_BAR_COLOR"
                android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="sub1.domain.ru"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="sub2.domain.ru"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="sub3.domain.ru"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

res\values\strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
    <string name="asset_statements">
        [{
            \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],
            \"target\": {
                \"namespace\": \"web\",
                \"site\": \"https://sub1.domain.ru\"}
        },{
            \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],
            \"target\": {
                \"namespace\": \"web\",
                \"site\": \"https://sub2.domain.ru\"}
        },{
            \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],
            \"target\": {
                \"namespace\": \"web\",
                \"site\": \"https://sub3.domain.ru\"}
        }]
    </string>
</resources>
```

res\values\styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.LauncherActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.domain.newsapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.github.GoogleChrome.custom-tabs-client:customtabs:91b4a1270b'
}
```

UPD
Added code from the files

Also seems like this behavior I was talking about is not a re-init but an overlay with another subdomain content over default that is opened but without action bar like in installed PWA and this leads to the problem that this overlay cannot be closed to return to the previous domain... And I really hoped that this might act like a normal browser tab and open every link in the same window...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you have any **code** that you can post to better describe the problem in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Google guys problem has been solved.

To be able to open links on other trusted domains inside the TWA app window and as a seamless transition in one tab (without additional overlay) I needed to use `android.support.customtabs.trusted.ADDITIONAL_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` and pass a string-array to in with required additional trusted domain as well as keeping only main one in intent with

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```

There is still a bug that needs to be solved since additional trusted origins still show URL bar but I hope it happens soon.

Reference on this in android-browser-helper's github
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/commit/24eefc89e69532d7f57fc83533886c9d762a41eb
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/commit/a1507153b420da6a3191fa23c64c5a0c06036e06

UPD
New version of android-browser-helper (1.2.0) finally has this issue fixed and multi-domain now is working as intended (additional trusted origins are verified correctly). Please pay attention to the changes in calling additional trusted origins array as stated in Demo within android-browser-helper.

Comment: Same situation here, adress bar is still showing, assetlinks and json files verified and working as the start url but in normal navigation redirects

Comment: Issue is fixed finally ) Please refer to android-browser-helper github for latest info.